# Log4Net is not creating logs in bin folder in Asp.Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to write logs in Asp.NEt Core 3.1 API. but it's not writing to the bin folder. instead, it has created the log file in the `Temp` folder in project directory.

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore version 3.1.0

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <file value="Temp\" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.'txt'"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level App  %newline %message %newline %newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is setting the folder to Temp: `<file value="Temp\" />`.

Change it to the full path of the `bin` folder or to the path of the `bin` folder relative to your `working directory` of your application.

For example: `.\` or `.\bin\`

By default Visual Studio will run your project and set the `working directory` to the project path.

On your project settings, in the Debug section you can manually override the `working directory` to bin, or you can change Launch mode from `Project` to `Executable` and select the executable on your bin folder.

Comment: It's still not creating file in bin folder, it's creating the the project folder itself

Comment: That depends on how you're executing the binaries. I`ve updated my answer to be more generic, so you can set the appropriate path for how you're starting the application.

Comment: I'm running the project from visual studio, so it should by default create file in bin folder,. With earlier .net versions it used to be like this

Comment: Well, in .NET Core it is not like that. When starting the server you should see that `Content Root Path` is set to your project folder and not the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

log4net will always use current directory (working directory)to as the root of realitve path defined in config file, so when application was started via VS, it is pointing to project folder, when application was started directly in bin folder, log file would be placed in bin folder.